# Generate Unique Id on Autocad MAP File

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocad

Hello i hope your are fine . i have problem i have a map file which is
created in Auto cad and this is a Housing Society MAP . I want unique
id off any part which is in map .(Can i generate auto unique id of
every part) . when user click any map part then i want to get information from data base and display on Pop.

i have worked on image map , i have create a coordinates and set unique id then fetch data from database using Unique ids this is work fine But i don't want to use image because housing society contain thousand off plots and housing i can't create thousands of coordinates i want to create auto unique id when i click  then get unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Each entity in AutoCAD has a Handle that is unique in the drawing and is persistent.  If you're accessing the entities via programming, it would be easier to get an entities ObjectID (which is essentially the Handle).

One thing to note: if an entity is modified (trimmed, modified, etc.) the Handle may change.